# Discord.js collector issue not updating embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to get it so that my discord bot will update the embed with the users reply, however I am not getting any errors and nothing in the console log.

So at the part where I think the issue is I do not get any console logs from that code. I have tried getting help with this and I cannot seem to get a solution on fixing this.

I will post a command in the discord chat (!start) the bot will then reply with 3 embeds it will then wait for a reply for 3 letters (UUU) then it is meant to update the embed with the reply from the user however for some unknown reason the code to me looks fine unless there is something there that isn't supported with discord.js.

**Full Code:**

```
const collector = battleChannel.createMessageCollector(filter, {max: 200, maxMatches: 200, time: 180000});
        collector.on('collect', m => {
            console.log(`Collected ${m.content} | ${m.author.username}`);

            if (game.data.length === 0 && m.content.length === 3){
                game.addID(m.content.toUppercase(), m.author.username);
            }else if (m.content.length === 3){
                if (game.userPresent(m.author.username)){
                    game.deleteUserEntry(m.author.username);
                    if (game.idPresent(m.content.toUppercase())){
                        game.addUser(m.content.toUppercase(), m.author.username);
                    }else {
                        game.addID(m.content.toUppercase(), m.author.username);
                    }
                } else {
                   if (game.idPresent(m.content.toUppercase())){
                       game.addUser(message.content.toUppercase(), message.author.username);
                   }else {
                       game.addID(m.content.toUppercase(), m.author.username);
                   }
                }
            }

            game.sort();

            let str = "";
            last3 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle ("Alliance joined!")
                .setColor ("#0099ff")
                .setTimestamp();

            for (var i = 0; i < game.data.length; i++){
                str = "";
                for (var j = 0; j < game.data[i].users.length; j++){
                    str += game.data[i].users[j] + "\n";
                }
                last3.addField(`${game.data[i].id.toUppercase()} - ${game.data[i].users.length} PLAYERS`, str, true);
            }

            editLast3.edit({embed: last3}).catch((err) => {
                console.log("Caught edit error");
            });

            if (m.deletable){
                m.delete().catch((err) => {
                    console.log("Cannot Delete");
                    console.log(err);
                });

                collector.on('end', collected => {
                    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
                });
            }

        });
        
    };
```

**Where I think the issue is:**

```
const collector = battleChannel.createMessageCollector(filter, {max: 200, maxMatches: 200, time: 180000});
        
        collector.on('collect', m => {
            console.log(`Collected ${m.content} | ${m.author.username}`);

            if (game.data.length === 0 && m.content.length === 3){
                game.addID(m.content.toUppercase(), m.author.username);
            }else if (m.content.length === 3){
                if (game.userPresent(m.author.username)){
                    game.deleteUserEntry(m.author.username);
                    if (game.idPresent(m.content.toUppercase())){
                        game.addUser(m.content.toUppercase(), m.author.username);
                    }else {
                        game.addID(m.content.toUppercase(), m.author.username);
                    }
                } else {
                   if (game.idPresent(m.content.toUppercase())){
                       game.addUser(message.content.toUppercase(), message.author.username);
                   }else {
                       game.addID(m.content.toUppercase(), m.author.username);
                   }
                }
            }

            game.sort();

            let str = "";
            last3 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle ("Alliance joined!")
                .setColor ("#0099ff")
                .setTimestamp();

            for (var i = 0; i < game.data.length; i++){
                str = "";
                for (var j = 0; j < game.data[i].users.length; j++){
                    str += game.data[i].users[j] + "\n";
                }
                last3.addField(`${game.data[i].id.toUppercase()} - ${game.data[i].users.length} PLAYERS`, str, true);
            }

            editLast3.edit({embed: last3}).catch((err) => {
                console.log("Caught edit error");
            });

            if (m.deletable){
                m.delete().catch((err) => {
                    console.log("Cannot Delete");
                    console.log(err);
                });

                collector.on('end', collected => {
                    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
                });
            }

        });
        
    };
```

Thank you for taking the time to look at this thread and assisting me.

Comment: Post your code **here**, not on an external site. And don't post your entire code, but a [mcve].

Comment: I have now posted the code, I posted the full code in that JS file.